# A button disable value is set to false by a function, but it is still set to be true right now

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, which will return a button( showing disabled always) and a function that disable it.

```
export const button = () => {

const isReadyToSimulate = () => {
    return false
  }

return(<>

 <Button kind="primary" size="md" disabled={isReadyToSimulate()} onClick={console.log}>
            Simualte
 </Button>
 
<>)


}
```

Question: However, the button disable value now is always true (not showing grey) why is that ?

Comment: Can you post the code/instructions through which you are getting disabled as true always?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it seems to work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/simulate-button-forked-6tdxmu

Comment: without () , it said   TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ButtonProps | Readonly<ButtonProps>): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ButtonProps, context: any): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: check the edited response